# How do I simulate GPS satellite data?

Tags: testing, design-patterns, frameworks, gis, satellite

I am trying to understand the algorithms used in GIS/GPS, and writing a program for that. However, the issue is with test data, which needs to simulate the reception from satellites on any random day.

The test data should be 
- a continuous stream from several sources that 
- changes in the number of sources (more satellites is more accuracy in calculation)
- should be broadcast with a unique timestamp but needs not be received in order of the timestamp

How should I go about it? Is there a software pattern for this? Any toolkits that do this sort of live "broadcasting"? 
[PS: I would be using either gcc or go, so something specific to those will be more useful]

Comment: My first idea would be to record live data and replay it. Wouldn't help with the "on any random day" - requirement though.

Comment: Did you ask here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/ if someone knows of some kind of simulator application?